# Lost traceId between Spring Boot services 2.x and 3.0 version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I have multiple services running with Spring Boot 2.7 and I am starting to create new services with Spring Boot 3.0. And I have the same problem as in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76159718/tracing-between-applications-on-spring-boot-2-and-spring-boot-3) but neither the accepted solution nor the attached migration guide has worked.
The behaviour during the requests is the next:

```
Service (2.7 - TraceId-X) -> Service (3.0 - TraceId-X) => OK
Service (3.0 - TraceId-X) -> Service (3.0 - TraceId-Y) => TraceId-X lost
Service (3.0 - TraceId-X) -> Service (2.7 - TraceId-Y) => TraceId-X lost
```

In short, when the request starts or goes through a service with version 3.0 the `traceId` is lost (it has been replaced by a new one).

application.yml (2.7):

```
spring.sleuth.propagation.type: w3c,b3
spring.sleuth.traceId128: true
spring.sleuth.supportsJoin: false
```

application.yml (3.0):

```
logging.pattern.level: "%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]"
```

The versions of the main dependencies are:
Services with 2.7 version:

- spring-boot: 2.7.7
- spring-cloud-starter-sleuth: 3.1.5

Services with 3.0 version:

- spring-boot: 3.0.6
- micrometer-tracing: 1.0.4
- micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave: 1.0.4

I can understand that there are integration problems between services of different versions, but there are also integration problems between Spring 3.0 services.
What could I be missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not like to answer my own question but I found the solution and maybe it will help someone in the future.

I did not realise that in most guides and tutorials on the internet they use `RestTemplate` to communicate between services. In my case, I am using `Feign` clients. And they need a specific library for `micrometer`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
  <artifactId>feign-micrometer</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer-support

Answer (score 1):

you have to update the `propagation.type` property in spring boot 3 project as well.

```
management.tracing.propagation.type=b3
```

and, make sure to add these dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already had those libraries added, I was missing the one I mentioned in my answer.